# Strange result using UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on here. I expect in the following query for the `rand_id` of record 5394560 in table `entities` to be updated to match the `rand_id` of the same record in table `unique_ids`. Instead it gets updated to 9?!?!?

```
mysql> update entities, unique_ids SET entities.rand_id = unique_ids.rand_id where entities.id=5394560;
Query OK, 1 rows affected (2.74 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Check of the results:

```
mysql> select * from entities where id=5394560;
+---------+------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id      | name             | rand_id | created_at          |
+---------+------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 5394560 | Andorra la Vella |       9 | 2013-03-15 13:58:38 |
+---------+------------------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from unique_ids where id=5394560;
+---------+----------+
| id      | rand_id  |
+---------+----------+
| 5394560 | 26543652 |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I missing something completely simple and stupid here?!?!? Both columns in both tables are using `int(11)`, so I don't think it's a problem with max value of the data type, but I could be wrong...

Comment: I guess it is the 'first' record in the primary key for uniques_ids

Answer (score 1):

you are missing any connection whatever between the two tables. besically the relation between  **entities** and **unique_ids** is not defined

try ading some "WHERE entities.something=unique_ids.somethingelse" where the something and somethingelse are names of columns from each of the table in question.

I believe this is your solution (note the "AND ..." part at the end):

```
update entities, unique_ids 
SET entities.rand_id = unique_ids.rand_id 
where entities.id=5394560 
    AND unique_ids.id=entities.id;
```

Comment: Ok, duh to me! You found the stupid thing I was missing! :-) Thanks.

Comment: @robguinness :) maybe you would find simpler using **UPDATE x LEFT JOIN y ON x.a=y.b SET .... WHERE ....** format instead